# Search for an empty list in DataDog query language

Tags: datadog

I have logs in datadog that look like this:

```
{"params": {"conversation_ids": [1, 2, 3]}}
```

I can find logs with an integer using the query:

```
@params.conversation_ids:2
```

How can i find logs with an empty list though?  For example:

```
{"params": {"conversation_ids": []}}
```